# Do I need to present user with admob EU consent form if my app is only published for country India?

Tags: android, admob

I saw notification regarding EU Consent form on Admob. I have published my app only for India. Do I still need to present user with consent form for users in India?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go through this [page](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/eu-consent#forward_consent_to_the_google_mobile_ads_sdk) by Google on collecting consent from users and integrating the Consent SDK it says

> the user is not located in the European Economic Area and consent is
>   not required under the EU User Consent Policy

So, no you are not required to show users of countries outside the European Economic Area with the consent form based on [EU User Consent Policy](https://www.google.com/about/company/consentstaging.html)